# Windows Server 2008 Stuck At Preparing to configure Windows

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server

I have a Windows Server 2008 Datacenter Edition VM on linux-xen.  It has been working fine until a few days ago apparently it attempted to install an update.  I have tried everything I can think of to get passed the 'Preparing to configure Windows' splash screen.

I have tried:

1. Booting into all three options of safe mode, all three performing the same splash screen step and endless reboot cycles.
2. Booting into last known good configuration, again boots to splash screen
3. F8, boot into repair, open cmd and use dism.exe /image:d:\ /remove-package PackageName:, which results in an error that I have found no information google about.
4. I have tried deleting windows\winsxs\pending.xml, it is currently deleted but still tries to configure updates.
5. Use dism.exe with the /revertpendingactions switch, which still brings me back to splash.

   `dism /image:D:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions`
6. Tried to repair via the installation disc, which does not have an OS repair option, just the same 3 options for Memory Diagnostics, Command Prompt and System Recovery

I did not realize that Windows Server 2008 DC Edition did not default to system restore points being enabled.  Apparently I have no restore points available to revert to.

I am going out of my mind trying to find some successful way to get passed this splash screen for configuring windows updates.  If the pending.xml file is missing then I do not understand how it could still be trying to configure updates.

I am at a loss, any additional troubleshooting steps or advice would be appreciated.  In terms of advice, I now realize I need to double check that restore points are enabled and take regular windows system recovery disk image backups so that I have better restoration capabilities in the future.

Being that this is on a linux-xen guest, I could duplicate it and try other means, but I am not sure what else there is to do.

Can I reinstall windows 2008 server back on top of it again and achieve some sort of success without breaking all of the licensing, rdp users, profiles, data ETC?  This server is not a member of a AD environment.  It is simply a standalone server that allows 10-12 users to RDP to access a few applications.

However, regardless how I move forward the data on the server is needed even if I were to opt for creating a new VM with a fresh install for them to use.

Is it possible to inform Windows to skip the update installation / configuration procedure during boot by adding a particular switch to the Boot options?  Currently it has:

`/NOEXECUTE=OPTOUT`

I am curious if it has some alternate runlevel like linux does that would potentially allow me to bypass this wretched situation.

Answer (score 4):

Mine was stuck until I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd>. It seems like it was a service pack that did it. I waited a few hours for it to finish when in fact all I had to do was hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd>.